# How to create custom Post in Redux WordPress Option Panel Framwork?

Tags: wordpress

I want to customize the slide option in redux admin panel, please have a look on the below screenshot, I want to add more input fields in it. How it is possible?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: I posted the same thing in github and got a reply with this link but as a beginner its looking too hard to understand, still I can't do anything with it!

http://docs.reduxframework.com/redux-framework/advanced/add-a-custom-field/

Comment: Yea, so right now it's not easy to make a custom field. You have to know PHP pretty ok. It's not difficult per say, but it is very PHP based.